# how to position div with css and force text to wrap around

Tags: html, css, position, word-wrap

I read previous posts and changed my CSS from an absolute position in order to get the text to wrap around.

I want this div to be position in the bottom right corner and for the text to move around it.

However, at the moment the text is forcing the div down.

Anyone have any idea on how to solve this?

html:

```
<div id="top-image">
        image
    </div>

    <p>dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text 
dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text 
dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text 
dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text 
dummy text      <br><br>

dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy 
text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy 
text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy 
text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy
text<p>


<div id="bottom-image">
    image
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#bottom{
float:left;
height:215px;
width:100%;
margin-top:10px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

#top-image{
    background-color:#999;
    float:left;
    width:140px;
    height:110px;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    }

#bottom-image{
    background-color:#999;
    float:right;
    width:140px;
    height:110px;
    margin-left:10px;
    }
```

This is what it looks like at the moment:
[image: screenshot]

As you can see the text is pushing the bottom image down into the footer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a `<p>` is a block level element it will always force other content down. If you place the image inside the paragraph it floats within the paragraph to the right. Just place it at the start of the line of text you want it to align with.

Answer (score 1):

Simple as that: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qiIob

You need to add float:left to your `<img>` and don't wrap your text into div or p.

Comment: but how can I force the image up and to fit into the main div?